# type='file' is not working in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

In angularjs ,i'm creating a form with following code but in the form type="file" is not properly showing.Is there anything to change in the code??

Thanks in advance.

```
 <form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST" action="apply.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate >
    <div class="form-group">   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" ng-model="user" 
       placeholder="Your Name" required>      
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="resume">Resume</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="file" type="file" name="file" required>       

        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="pointer" value="Apply" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">

    </form>
```

sample screenshot for the above code is shown below
[image]

Comment: should be an issue with css

Comment: i'm using bootstrapCDN for css @sejeetharan

Comment: try adding inline CSS to check if it is CSS issue  <input style='height:30px;width:100px' class="form-control" id="file" type="file" name="file" required>

Comment: Still not working.just adding one another line under resume..@TariqRasheed

Comment: try inspect code and check if element exists in the dom and what style is active.

Comment: I tried your code and it looks ok except the apply button since I don't have the `pointer` class. The issue must be with your pointer class. Check whether it has a fixed position that overlaps the file input field.