# Not able to enable a button with ng-disabled in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

This is what I have in my controller.js

```
$scope.fileAdded = false;

$scope.fileNameChanged = function() {
    $scope.fileAdded = true;
};
```

This button I want to enable ...

```
<a ng-disabled="!fileAdded" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Click</a>
```

... when I choose a file:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)">
```

Although `fileAdded` changes from false to true, the button is not enabled. Why is it still disabled?

Comment: For better ways to do this, see [ng-model for <input type=“file”/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file/43074638#43074638).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With onchange you are out of angularJS. So you need to trigger the digect cycle by yourself:

```
$scope.fileNameChanged = function() {
    $scope.fileAdded = true;
    $scope.$digest();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Angular's ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive, as opposed to the DOM `onchange`.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" ng-change="fileNameChanged()">
```

Comment: The `ng-change` directive doesn't work without the `ng-model` directive. And the `ng-model` directive doesn't work with `<input type="file:`.  See [type='file' is not working in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653526/type-file-is-not-working-in-angularjs).

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that, thanks @georgeawg. Learn something everyday :)